# Vue.js, show image dynamically after downloading it

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, vue.js, download

I'm working in Vue.js / Node.js (express.js) 
And trying to show an image after downloading it via GET request (by Axios) from server.
The file is uploaded by a user so we don't know about it's details (length or etc.).
And after download, it needs to be shown to the user.
Server after receiving the download request, simply gets the file from disk and put it in response:

```
(req, res) => {
    ...
    res.download(file)
}
```

In client I did this so far, 
 after downloading the file, I convert it to Base64 string:

```
Buffer.from(response.data, 'binary').toString('base64')
```

(response of GET request) 
And try to showing it on my template like this:

```
:src="'data:image/png;base64,' + myBase64string"
```

And wasn't successful at all ! 
Really appreciate any advice, suggestion, help or etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the great help of @Shivam Singh and this handy git repo 
[download-file.js](https://gist.github.com/javilobo8/097c30a233786be52070986d8cdb1743),
I could solve the problem. 
**Response type** of the request (Axios request) should be 
**responseType: 'blob'** 
And after receiving data from server, I simply used this line of code below to generate a DOM string and then place it as src to an image tag:

```
const imageUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]))

<img :src="imageUrl ">
```

According to [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) URL.createObjectURL method, creates a DOMString containing a URL representing the object given in the parameter. The URL lifetime is tied to the document in the window on which it was created.

Answer (score 2):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data () {
    return {
      src: null
    }
  },
 
  mounted () {
    let self = this
    fetch("https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/freely-accessible-examination-exposition-mosaic-ar-figures-mosaic-st-petersburg-russia-june-freely-accessible-119320551.jpg")
    .then((response) => {
      response.blob().then(blobResponse => {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(blobResponse); 
        reader.onloadend = function() {
          let base64data = reader.result; 
          let img = document.createElement('img')
          img.src = base64data  
          self.$refs['img-container'].appendChild(img)
        }
      })
    })
  }
})
```

```css
img {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div ref="img-container"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Shivam Singh, thank you for your answer. It didn't worked for me, my server sends data differently (my response is different than yours). But your answer guide me to solve my problem. Really appreciate it.

Comment: please update the question with the response from your server, also please upvote if you found it helpful. Thanks